# "Method saveas of object _workbook failed" when same name file present in directory

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am trying to save a file in the directory if the file is saved again excel message appears. I am new to vba error handling, stuck in this project code

[image]

if "NO" is pressed it gives the subject error. Here is my code:

```
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim x As String
    With Destwb

    On Error Resume Next

        .SaveAs TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum


       If Sheet1.Cells(2, 6) = "All" Then
Exit Sub
End If
'Destwb.Sheets("REC_INT").Range("A1").Select

If Not Sheet1.Cells(2, 6) = "All" Then
x = Sheet1.Range("L3")

        With OutMail
            .To = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3).Value
            .CC = Sheet1.Cells(x, 4).Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Service Record"
            .Body = Sheet1.Cells(8, 7).Value
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            '.Send   'or use
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End If
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    'Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Why isn't the Error Skipped?

Comment: It should give error as VBA is not able to save it. You want to skip the Error ?

Comment: Yes to handle this error

Comment: Handle in What Sense ? You wanna skip it ? Ask you a different name to save ? Overwrite the File ? Your Question is not clear.

Comment: Yes to skip it and move on with the code if no is pressed

Comment: Put this line on top of your code. `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: May try this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-vba-run-time-error-1004-with-saveas-if/5432c143-3f5a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- `On Error Resume Next` is after the line that saves the file

This will continue the code without saving the file.

**Solution:**

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim x As String

On Error Resume Next


With Destwb
       .Save True
       '.SaveAs TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

If Sheet1.Cells(2, 6) = "All" Then
    Exit Sub

Else

    x = Sheet1.Range("L3")

        With OutMail
            .To = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3).Value
            .CC = Sheet1.Cells(x, 4).Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Service Record"
            .Body = Sheet1.Cells(8, 7).Value
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            '.Send   'or use
            .Display
        End With

On Error GoTo 0

        .Close savechanges:=False

End If
End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    'Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: by doing this it is not attaching my file; I want to not save it but send it via mail, I have updated the remaining code...

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are attaching a file Mate !, neither did you mention that you are. Edit your question and explain clearly what you want and what is happening.

Comment: just edited the code sorry delay due to bad connection

Comment: And if you want to click No only, why do have that line of code ? I would say get rid of it.

Comment: @UmarFarooq, Try running your code by pressing `F8` i.e step wise, and mention where you are running into problem.

Comment: Ok can i skip this and just simply overwrite the file everytime?

Comment: It is not overwriting at the moment. It is not saving the file. Skipping the Error isn't solving it. It just continues the code without looking at the error ?

Comment: yes I want to overwrite everything instead of asking this message